# React react definitely typed Upgrading to react 18 issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, types

**EDIT**: I 've added the following error from a thid party library that use `children` from a component however is breaks my code

here's a sample error of a third party library `Draggable` i'm using:

> Type '{ children: Element; bounds: string; cancel: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Pick<Readonly<Partial>, never> & InexactPartial<...> & InexactPartial<...>'.

I'm using react typescript and I've decided to update to react 18 version, however doing so has broken my application. I've checked this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304#issuecomment-1094565891), it describes the same issue from my side, however I'm still getting the same errors especially for ones that require the `children` as a prop to a component and for third party libraries that I'm using!

What I've done is using the `overrides` in my `package.json` and installing the `react` and `react-dom` and `@types/react-dom` so my `package.json` is like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
     // other installed third party libraries
}, 
"devDependencies": { 
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    // other developement libraries
},
"overrides": {
     "@types/react": "^18.0.0"
}
```

Comment: `broken my application`,  in what way, any errors?

Comment: `Parameter 'id' implicitly has an 'any type.  TS7006` this error just appeared after upgrading to react 18 it 's basically a function that's passed to a third party library component as a prop @Keith

Comment: That doesn't really help, unless you show the code that's doing this.

Comment: @Keith sorry for the confusion i 've updated the question with an example error

Comment: `Draggable` isn't typed to support React 18. Wherever that is, you should upgrade it or replace it to a something that supports React 18. Perhaps https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hello-pangea/dnd ?